# How to find value of pi 5 digit by leibniz's series

Tags: c++

I am starting to learn C++ and I have a problem with my code. I want to find the pi value using the Leibniz series and also the number of iterations to reach five significant digits (3.14159) but it's doesn't work.

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include <math.h>
  using namespace std;

 int main(){
      double pi = 0.0;
      int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 10000 ; i++){
       pi += 4*pow(-1,i)/(2*i+1);
       if ( pi == 3.14159){
       cout<<i;
       break;
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" in more technical terms?

Comment: Hint: In floating point math you're extremely unlikely to get a value that matches 3.14159 *precisely*, especially when you're using a method like this that will introduce a lot of noise into that value as it approaches the limit. If you want to test a particular decimal place, consider `if (pi * 100000 % 10 == N)` or something like that.

Comment: @tadman It didn't output anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @tadman so how can I find the interaction when pi = 3.14159? please help me

Comment: Tip: Print every intermediate result. You're unlikely to find one that matches that value precisely.

Comment: As computed here, `pi` will never, ever equal that value.

Comment: Hint: To see the *actual* values you can't depend on defaults, you need to ask for more detail, like `std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << pi << std::endl;` via `<iomanip>`. What you get with defaults only shows a fixed number of places and can lead you astray, it's not the actual value.

Comment: Never ever use the == operator on floating point values. Instead of `x==y` use `abs(x-y) < tolerance` where `tolerance` is a small positive number, e.g. `1e-6` (the actual value must be chosen to fit the situation).

Answer (score 0):

You may check if the absolute difference between the computed value via Leibniz series and the "true" value of pi is below a given tolerance. Instead of using 3.14159 as value for pi, you may use the built-in constant contained in `math.h`: `M_PI`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
  double pi = 0.0;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 10000 ; i++){
      // i-th value via Lieibniz formula
      pi += 4*pow(-1,i)/(2*i+1);
      // Check if the difference is below a given tolerance equal to 0.0001
      if (abs(pi - M_PI)<0.0001){
          // Print the iteration at which the given tolerance is achieved
          std::cout<<i<< std::endl;
          // Break the for cycle
          break;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The above code checks if the absolute difference between the approximated value and the "true" value of pi is below 0.0001.

You may also check if the *relative* difference from the actual value is below a given tolerance, by substituting the check with

```
if (abs(pi - M_PI)/M_PI<0.0001){
  // Print the iteration at which the given tolerance is achieved
  std::cout<<i<< std::endl;
  // Break the for cycle
  break;
}
```

---

In your code, the variable `count` is unused. Let me give you a little advice: [do not use `using namespace::std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/13156261).

Comment: Thanks you so much;)

Comment: @Napole Glad to help! If you find that the answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted for future users! If you need any guidance about posting question&answers, accepting answers and using SO, have a look at the [tour] and/or visit the [help].